# How does GridPanel determine the size?

Tags: swing, scala, grid-layout, gridpanel

Here is a very simple Scala GUI test:

```
import scala.swing._

object FirstSwingApp extends SimpleGUIApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = new GridPanel(30, 20) {
      contents ++= 1 to 600 map (_ => new Label("test"))
    }
  }
}
```

Every contained label is displayed exactly as big as it needs to be:

[image: test]

Now I want to replace `Label` with a custom type:

```
contents ++= 1 to 600 map (_ => new Foo)

class Foo extends Panel {
  override def minimumSize = {
    println("minimumSize")
    new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32)
  }

  override def preferredSize = {
    println("preferredSize")
    new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32)
  }

  override def maximumSize = {
    println("maximumSize")
    new java.awt.Dimension(32, 32)
  }
}
```

But the result is way too small:

[image: test2]

Apparently, none of the `xxxSize` methods gets called, because the program produces no console output. What exactly do I have to change so that each `Foo` is displayed with a size of 32x32 pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `scala.swing` is just a wrapper around `javax.swing`. And `Label`, in this case, is just an instance, that is wrapped around `javax.swing.JLabel`.

And when the component is being passed to `javax.swing` system, only the component is passed, not the wrapper.

Thus, overriding methods on wrappers will do you no good.

But you can override methods on the actual component instance. For example:

```
import scala.swing._
import javax.swing._
import java.awt.Dimension
import javax.swing.JPanel

object Swg extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  class Foo extends Panel {
    override lazy val peer: JPanel = new JPanel with SuperMixin {
      override def getMinimumSize = new Dimension(32, 32)
      override def getPreferredSize = new Dimension(32, 32)
      override def getMaximumSize = new Dimension(32, 32)
    }
  }

  def top = new MainFrame {
    contents = new GridPanel(30, 20) {
      contents ++= List.fill(600)(new Foo)
    }
  }
}
```

On my machine, that gives a frame of 640 px wide and about 960 px high - which is probably what you want.

Comment: +1 Excellent! Very readable. Does `App` do [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) on behalf of it's clients?

Comment: @trashgod - In this case, App does nothing related to Swing - it's just a runner of standard application. But scala has similar class, named `SimpleSwingApplication`, that does run all that code on EDT. I'll edit the answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

As Rogach said, the problem is you don't change the underlying peer. Another possibility to do that is the following:

```
class Foo extends Panel {
   preferredSize = new Dimension(32, 32)
}
```